# Flink checkpointing state for non-keyed stream

Tags: apache-flink

I am new to Flink. I am trying to enable checkpointing and stateful in my application. I saw how we store keyed state from the Flink documents. But I am wondering can we store non-keyed state (state for `ProcessFunction`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's somewhat unusual to need non-keyed state, but there is [documentation with examples](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/state/state.html#using-operator-state).

In user code this is generally only needed for implementing custom sources and sinks, which is why the examples focus on those use cases. But in a `ProcessFunction` you would do the same, i.e., implement the `CheckpointedFunction` interface (i.e., the `initializeState` and `snapshotState` methods).

The only types of non-keyed state are `ListState`, `UnionState`, and `BroadcastState`, and `ListState` is probably the type you want to use. `UnionState` is very similar to `ListState`, it just uses a different strategy for redistributing state during rescaling (each parallel instance gets the entire list, instead of being assigned a slice of the list, and the instances are responsible for knowing what to do). `BroadcastState` is what's used by a `BroadcastProcessFunction` or `KeyedBroadcastProcessFunction`.